# How can you find two solutions to $\cos(3x - \frac{\pi}{2}) = 0$ by illustrating the situation on the unit circle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> How can you find two solutions to $\cos(3x -  \frac{\pi}{2}) = 0$ by illustrating the situation on the unit circle?

The solutions I got for this are $x = 0+2\pi k$ or $\pi/3 + 2\pi k$ where $k$ is an integer. I got this algebraically, but I do not know how to picture this on the unit circle or find the solutions that way.

Comment: Your question should be independent of the title. In particular, it should have a self-contained body.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Hint: Stop thinking in terms of $x$ and start thinking in terms of $3x-\frac{\pi}{2}$. For what values of $3x-\frac{\pi}{2}$ does $\cos(3x-\frac{\pi}{2})=0$?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As you can see on the given picture of the unit circle, it is fairly easy to

find the solutions.$0$ is another way to say $360$ degrees. Starting from

$\pi/2$, it goes $\pi/3$,$\pi/4$,,then $\pi/6$.The points given, are also easy

to remember, for the top $cos=1,2,3$ down and $sin=3,2,1$ down.Just flip that

tactic around when getting to the bottom of the unit circle. Graphing this problem, would be the first approach I would have to this problem, which would involve knowing these points.I think the directions may have meant to use the values from the unit circle in order to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have $ \cos(3x-\frac{\pi}{2}) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \sin(3x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow x = \frac{\pi n}{3} $ where $n \in \mathbb Z$.

Geometrically, that's the $x$ spots on the horizontal $x'x$ line, that when you draw a perpendicular line to $x'x$ and connect the intersection of the perpendicular line and the unit circle with $(0,0)$, you get an angle which is one of the solutions.

Comment: What is x' x? I only learned this concept in terms of the unit circle.

Comment: The unit circle is drawn in the cartesian coordinate system. The $x'x$ and $y'y$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle